# boost::shared_ptr use_count

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr

I'm trying to understand what's going on in the following code.  When object-a is deleted, does it's shared_ptr member variable object-b remains in memory because object-c holds a shared_ptr to object-b?

```
    class B
    {
    public:
       B(int val)
       {
          _val = val;
       }
       int _val;
    };

    class A
    {
    public:
       A()
       {
          _b = new B(121);
       }
       boost::shared_ptr<B> _b;
    };

    class C
    {
    public:
       C()
       {
       }

       void setRef( boost::shared_ptr<B> b)
       {
          _b = b;
       }
       boost::shared_ptr<B> _b;
    };

    int main()
    {
       C c;
       {
          A *a = new A();       
          cout << "a._b.use_count: " << a->_b.use_count() << endl;
          c.setRef(a->_b);
          cout << "a._b.use_count: " << a->_b.use_count() << endl;
                  delete a;
       }
       cout << c._b->_val << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `A`-object will be cleaned up as soon as `a` is deleted at the end of its block. But the shared_ptr it contains was subsequently copied, incrementing its reference count.

Thus, the `B`-object will have a reference count of 2 after `c.setRef` (referenced by the `A`-object and by the `C`-object's `shared_ptr`). When `a` is deleted at the end of its block, then the reference count of the `B`-object drops to `1` again since only `c`'s shared_ptr is referencing it now.

After `c` is destroyed at the end of main, its `shared_ptr` will be destroyed too as part of `c`'s destruction, and now as the reference count drops to zero, the pointed-to `B` object will be deleted by `shared_ptr`.

So, the reference counts of the `B`-object:

```
0: before existence of a.
1: from start of lifetime of a until c.setRef
2: from c.setRef until copy of its parameter
3: from copy of c.setRef''s parameter until return of it
2: from return of c.setRef until end of a''s block
1: from end of a''s block until end of main
0: after main returned (object doesn''t exist anymore now)
```

Answer (score 2):

No, when a is deleted, a->_b (the pointer itself) will cease to exist.

The **object** that a->_b points to will continue to exist, because c._b still points to it.

Answer (score 0):

The target of the `shared_ptr` will remain live until the final reference to it is deleted. In this case, this will be when the `C` instance goes out of scope.